# Extracting execution DAG from PyTorch Module

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Let us consider a simple feed-forward deep net or even a resnet. In both case, you can think of the execution flow as a DAG (directed acyclic graph) where nodes are layers (it's a chain if there's no skip connexion).

For some reason, I need this DAG for pyTorch models. Up to now I have been using custom object subclassing nn.Module (that stores the information that I need) but I would like to be able ultimately to use an arbitrary model in input of my pipeline. Is there a way to extract this DAG automatically ? (it does not matter if it's not working in all cases, I am mainly looking for general ideas / principles to achieve my goal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed possible. Consider following evaluation of a simple formula as a stand in for a more complicated network:

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
b = 3*a + 1
c = torch.relu(b)
d = c.sum()
```

Then `d` has a `.grad_fn` attribute, from which you can recurse through the evaluation graph like so

```
d.grad_fn
d.grad_fn.next_functions
d.grad_fn.next_functions
d.grad_fn.next_functions[0][0].next_functions
d.grad_fn.next_functions[0][0].next_functions[0][0].next_functions
```

Basically `next_functions` gives you a list of the arguments to the current module/operation, and each entries of this list is a tuple with the actual object, as well as an integer that indicates the position of the argument. This is documented in more detail [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/autograd_tutorial.html#tensors-that-track-history).

If you don't want to do it yourself, you can also use the visualization tool for the computation graph that is built into tensorboard, that is `SummaryWriter.add_graph()` as documented [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_graph).

Comment: Thanks ! Seems that next_functions is the right entry point for me !